# Для утверждения правки нужен голос ещё одного участника - почему?

Tags: предложение

У меня имеется (заработано) право корректировки вопроса/ответа участника единолично. Аппрува других участников не требуется.

В то же время для аппрува чужой правки, если автор правки такой привилегии не заработал, одного моего аппрува недостаточно, нужен ещё один голос "за". При этом если я выберу "Улучшить правку", она будет принята сразу, даже если не вносить изменений в исходную правку (правда, при этом я "украду" авторство корректировки, что не есть хорошо).

Вам не кажется, что всё это слегка нелогично?

Предлагаю для участников, имеющих право единоличной корректировки вопросов и ответов, отключить подобную проверку.

Comment: workaround: _принять и улучшить_, _отклонить и править_

Comment: _при этом я "украду" авторство корректировки_ - вроде как предложенная правка автоматом принимается, поэтому о краже речи нет, просто будет по сути две правки

Comment: @Grundy раздувание ревизий.

Answer (score 4):

Подобное предложение неоднократно поднималось на MSE. Наиболее подходящее как по смыслу, так и по словам, кмк, вот это: [Instant edit approval for high-rep users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94581/339911). Вопрос закрыт дубликатом на следующий: [Instant approval of revisions for users with edit privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85758/339911), уже помеченный как [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). Тем не менее, как следует из [ответа сотрудника](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290913/339911), поставившего упомянутую метку:

> If you're not also editing (whether that's to improve upon the suggested edit, or replace it entirely), then arguably your privilege means nothing in this context.

> Если вы не редактируете предлагаемую правку, привилегия дающая возможность единоличного редактирования ничего не значит в этом контексте.

Таким образом, правильнее было бы поставить метку [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), но пути SOтрудников неисповедимы. В общем, не стоит ожидать, что возможность единоличной правки даст возможность единоличного утверждения правки без каких-либо её модификаций.

По поводу кражи предлагаемой правки при выборе пункта "улучшить правку": никакой кражи не происходит, в списке ревизий предложенная правка остаётся видна ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/964593/revisions)), а вторым участником её утвердившим становится Дух. Он приходит на помощь, когда вы идёте по пути улучшения правки или её отклонения с редактированием сообщения.